# Custom email domain with icloud+ - how to have it as a separate account in Mail?

Tags: icloud, email, icloud-plus

I have a custom domain (ravnand.dk) where I have migrated emails to iCloud+

This appears to work nicely, but it seems that all the iCloud related mails end in the same inbox in the Mail app which I do not want as I use the non-custom iCloud account for other unrelated things.   I would like my iPhone to treat my custom emails as a separate account similar to how it worked when I was using another provider.  I did not immediately see any help pages describing this when browsing the iCloud+ documentation.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Haven‘t tried it, but could you use mail rules on iCloud.com to put mails into folders by address?